# Get JSON key from Node.js server to ejs page

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I render an ejs page from Node.js server, in ejs I get JSON like:

```
A[
  {
    "name1":"abc",
    "name2":"xyz",
    "2018/05/10":"2",
    "2018/05/12":"4",
    "2018/05/20":"20"
  },
  {
    "name1":"def",
    "name2":"xxx",
    "2018/05/10":"23",
    "2018/05/12":"34",
    "2018/05/20":"0"
  },
  {.....},
  {......}
]
```

I want to render ejs like:

```
name1-------name2--------2018/05/10-------2018/05/12-------2018/05/20

abc-------------xyz----------2--------------------------4-------------------20

def------------xxxx----------23-------------------------34----------------0
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try ways see

```js
//app.js
 var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');//import library
app.get('/lists', function(req, res){
   var data=jsonfile.readFileSync("lists.json");//reac file json
   res.render("show",data);
});


//show.ejs
<% lists.forEach(function(rows){%>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rows.name1%></td>
            <td><%=rows.name2%></td>
            <td><%=rows.date1%></td>
            <td><%=rows.date2%></td>
            <td><%=rows.date3%></td>
        </tr>
<%})%>
```

```html
//you can create file json lists.json
"lists:[
      {
        "name1":"abc",
        "name2":"xyz",
        "date1":"2",
        "date2":"4",
        "date3":"20"
      }
]
```